# Unwanted pipelines triggers

Tags: azure-devops

I have next structure of my repo in Azure's VisualStudio:

```
development ↴
            - Branch1
            - Branch2
```

I have a **pipeline.yaml** in the development branch:

```
trigger:
  - development

pool:
  vmImage: ubuntu-latest

variables:
  - name: DEPLOYMENT
    value: development

jobs:
  - job: Print evironment
    steps:
      - script: printenv | sort
```

I have a pipeline linked to that file in development branch. Also I have a policy to run that pipeline for pull requests.

And I have two problems with this config.

1. When I am pushing anything into ANY branch that has that **pileline.yaml** file - pipeline will be triggered for that branch. And that affects all the branches nested from development branch
2. When I am creating a pull request - it is triggering the build. But if I am pushing changes to the branch then two builds are triggering. One for the branch itself and one for pull request.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How did you create the structure of my repo? The `development` is the branch folder? Could you please share the structure of my repo with image?

Comment: I can not make any screenshot unfortunately. The "development" is a branch from which other branches are created and to which they supposed to be merged

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem was in trigger syntax

This is working as explained in the question:

```
trigger:
  - development
```

This is working as expected:

```
trigger:
  branches:
    include:
      - development
```